# How to send S3 secured file as an attachment in email in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am using Ruby on Rails application and need to send an email with an attachment of S3 secured file.

Below is my sample Mailer

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(s3_obj)
    attachments['sample.csv'] = open(s3_obj.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 60)).read
    mail(to: "galet@gmail.com", subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end  
end
```

I am getting error as follows when I execute `UserMailer.welcome_email(s3_obj).deliver_now`

> WARN: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

How to add S3 secured file as an email attachment in Rails? Also I want to send the original file name

Comment: Is it the full error stack?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue after using "require 'open-uri'" in the UserMailer.